# Any way to delay firing Embers model in beforeModel hook?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, loading

I need to add spinning loader to component. My component observing global object `global.loading`. I'm setting `global.loading` to `true` in `beforeModel` hook in my `route`.

The problem that there is some sort of race-condition: UI thread gets blocked by the model before loading spinner appears.

Is there any way i can delay model from `beforeModel`?

Or i need to come up with different strategy?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Ember loading states as I haven't made use of them yet but it is covered fairly well in the guide.  Have you seen this info?  If you have and it's not useful I apologize: (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/loading-and-error-substates/)  (http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/asynchronous-routing/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you return a promise from `beforeModel`, the transition will pause until the promise fulfills.

I can't speak to whether that will solve your specific problem, but that's how `beforeModel` works.

Comment: Excellent! If i return promise and resolve it with Ember.run.later it does the trick! Thanks a lot!